# Extracting specific texts between square brackets in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, string, preg-match

I am getting data from the WordPress database. The data is like

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [post_content] => [et_pb_section fb_built="1" admin_label="Hero" _builder_version="3.22" use_background_color_gradient="on" background_color_gradient_start="rgba(40,40,40,0.79)" background_color_gradient_end="rgba(40,40,40,0.86)" background_color_gradient_type="radial" background_color_gradient_direction_radial="top left" background_color_gradient_overlays_image="on" background_image="https://waydevelopers.tech/const/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/construction-35.jpg" custom_margin="||||false" custom_padding="10vw||10vw||true|false"][et_pb_row _builder_version="3.25"][et_pb_column type="4_4" _builder_version="3.25" custom_padding="|||" custom_padding__hover="|||"][et_pb_divider color="#ffb400" divider_position="center" divider_weight="5px" _builder_version="3.9" max_width="50px" module_alignment="center" locked="off"][/et_pb_divider][et_pb_text `module_id="homehead1"` _builder_version="4.8.0" text_font="||||||||" header_font="Rubik|700|||||||" header_font_size="64px" header_line_height="1.1em" text_orientation="center" background_layout="dark" max_width="800px" module_alignment="center" custom_margin="||0px|" custom_padding="|||16px" text_font_size_tablet="14px" text_font_size_last_edited="off|desktop" header_font_size_tablet="44px" header_font_size_phone="32px" header_font_size_last_edited="on|phone"]
> USA Construction
> [/et_pb_text][et_pb_text module_id="homesubhead1" _builder_version="4.8.0" text_font="||||||||" text_font_size="22px" text_line_height="1.6em" header_font="||||||||" text_orientation="center" background_layout="dark" max_width="800px" module_alignment="center" custom_margin="|||" custom_padding="20px||20px||true" text_font_size_tablet="18px" text_font_size_phone="" text_font_size_last_edited="on|phone"]Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam lectus erat consectetur eu sapien eget, rhoncus consectetur sem.[/et_pb_text][/et_pb_column][/et_pb_row][/et_pb_section][et_pb_section fb_built="1" admin_label=" Get a Quote" _builder_version="3.22" custom_padding="|||" animation_style="slide" animation_direction="top" animation_intensity_slide="10%" box_shadow_style="preset3" box_shadow_vertical="10px" box_shadow_blur="105px" box_shadow_spread="0px" box_shadow_color="rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"][et_pb_row column_structure="1_3,1_3,1_3" _builder_version="3.25" background_color="#ffffff" max_width="80%" custom_margin="|||" use_custom_width="on" width_unit="off"][et_pb_column type="1_3" _builder_version="3.25" custom_padding="|||" custom_padding__hover="|||"][et_pb_blurb title="Building Construction" image="https://waydevelopers.tech/const/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/construction-icon-7-gray.png" icon_placement="left" image_max_width="64px" content_max_width="1100px" content_max_width_tablet="1100px" content_max_width_last_edited="off|desktop" module_id="homeblurb1" _builder_version="4.8.0" header_font="Rubik|700|||||||" header_line_height="1.4em" body_font="||||||||" body_font_size="15px" body_line_height="1.8em" custom_margin="|||" custom_padding="|||" animation_style="slide" animation_direction="right" animation_intensity_slide="10%" animation="off" locked="off"]

I want to extract data within the square brackets by giving the `module_id` as highlighted in the data above
And returning the data as `et_pb_text module_id="homehead1" _builder_version="4.8.0" text_font="||||||||" header_font="Rubik|700|||||||" header_font_size="64px" header_line_height="1.1em" text_orientation="center" background_layout="dark" max_width="800px" module_alignment="center" custom_margin="||0px|" custom_padding="|||16px" text_font_size_tablet="14px" text_font_size_last_edited="off|desktop" header_font_size_tablet="44px" header_font_size_phone="32px" header_font_size_last_edited="on|phone"`

and Also the Content between the respective blocks
like

> USA Construction

in between [et_pb_text...]Data to be extracted[/et_pb_text]

I tried preg match and other solutions but no luck at all
I tried first converting the array to string and then applying preg match

```
$nn=json_encode($database);
preg_match_all("/\[[^\]]*\]/", $nn, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: You could match `\[\Ket_pb_text module_id="homehead1"[^][]*(?=])` https://regex101.com/r/7lTuo3/1

Comment: Did the answer work out?

Comment: Yes, it Worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that string comes from the database, you can make the match more specific without matching the square brackets themselves and you don't have to use json_encode.

```
\[\Ket_pb_text module_id="homehead1"[^][]*(?=])
```

The pattern matches

- `\[\K` Match `[` and reset the starting point of the reported match (clear the match buffer)
- `et_pb_text module_id="homehead1"` Match literally to make the pattern more specific
- `[^][]*` Match any char except `[` and `]`
- `(?=])` Assert `]` at the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KEx5Mx/1) | [php demo](https://3v4l.org/b03dt).

```
$database = <<<DATABASE
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [post_content] => [et_pb_section fb_built="1" admin_label="Hero" _builder_version="3.22" use_background_color_gradient="on" background_color_gradient_start="rgba(40,40,40,0.79)" background_color_gradient_end="rgba(40,40,40,0.86)" background_color_gradient_type="radial" background_color_gradient_direction_radial="top left" background_color_gradient_overlays_image="on" background_image="https://waydevelopers.tech/const/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/construction-35.jpg" custom_margin="||||false" custom_padding="10vw||10vw||true|false"][et_pb_row _builder_version="3.25"][et_pb_column type="4_4" _builder_version="3.25" custom_padding="|||" custom_padding__hover="|||"][et_pb_divider color="#ffb400" divider_position="center" divider_weight="5px" _builder_version="3.9" max_width="50px" module_alignment="center" locked="off"][/et_pb_divider][et_pb_text module_id="homehead1" _builder_version="4.8.0" text_font="||||||||" header_font="Rubik|700|||||||" header_font_size="64px" header_line_height="1.1em" text_orientation="center" background_layout="dark" max_width="800px" module_alignment="center" custom_margin="||0px|" custom_padding="|||16px" text_font_size_tablet="14px" text_font_size_last_edited="off|desktop" header_font_size_tablet="44px" header_font_size_phone="32px" header_font_size_last_edited="on|phone"] USA Construction [/et_pb_text][et_pb_text module_id="homesubhead1" _builder_version="4.8.0" text_font="||||||||" text_font_size="22px" text_line_height="1.6em" header_font="||||||||" text_orientation="center" background_layout="dark" max_width="800px" module_alignment="center" custom_margin="|||" custom_padding="20px||20px||true" text_font_size_tablet="18px" text_font_size_phone="" text_font_size_last_edited="on|phone"]Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam lectus erat consectetur eu sapien eget, rhoncus consectetur sem.[/et_pb_text][/et_pb_column][/et_pb_row][/et_pb_section][et_pb_section fb_built="1" admin_label=" Get a Quote" _builder_version="3.22" custom_padding="|||" animation_style="slide" animation_direction="top" animation_intensity_slide="10%" box_shadow_style="preset3" box_shadow_vertical="10px" box_shadow_blur="105px" box_shadow_spread="0px" box_shadow_color="rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"][et_pb_row column_structure="1_3,1_3,1_3" _builder_version="3.25" background_color="#ffffff" max_width="80%" custom_margin="|||" use_custom_width="on" width_unit="off"][et_pb_column type="1_3" _builder_version="3.25" custom_padding="|||" custom_padding__hover="|||"][et_pb_blurb title="Building Construction" image="https://waydevelopers.tech/const/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/construction-icon-7-gray.png" icon_placement="left" image_max_width="64px" content_max_width="1100px" content_max_width_tablet="1100px" content_max_width_last_edited="off|desktop" module_id="homeblurb1" _builder_version="4.8.0" header_font="Rubik|700|||||||" header_line_height="1.4em" body_font="||||||||" body_font_size="15px" body_line_height="1.8em" custom_margin="|||" custom_padding="|||" animation_style="slide" animation_direction="right" animation_intensity_slide="10%" animation="off" locked="off"]
DATABASE;

preg_match_all('/\[\Ket_pb_text module_id="homehead1"[^][]*(?=])/', $database, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(474) "et_pb_text module_id="homehead1" _builder_version="4.8.0" text_font="||||||||" header_font="Rubik|700|||||||" header_font_size="64px" header_line_height="1.1em" text_orientation="center" background_layout="dark" max_width="800px" module_alignment="center" custom_margin="||0px|" custom_padding="|||16px" text_font_size_tablet="14px" text_font_size_last_edited="off|desktop" header_font_size_tablet="44px" header_font_size_phone="32px" header_font_size_last_edited="on|phone""
}
```

Using json_encode, you would have to account for the backslashes

```
preg_match_all('/\[\Ket_pb_text module_id=\\\\"homehead1\\\\"[^][]*(?=])/', $nn, $matches);
```

Comment: You can use the same pattern and change homehead1 to text1 https://regex101.com/r/8C82Hn/1

Comment: Can you optimize this regex? I tried using the points in your answer.
https://regex101.com/r/jlLI6F/2

Comment: I want the same result as now in this regex 
https://regex101.com/r/jlLI6F/2

Comment: If you want the dot to match a newline you can use the s flag or inline modifier `(?s)` like https://regex101.com/r/uuHbeC/1 Using the negated character class to not match `[` or `]` will not work in this case because this part `edited="on|phone"]` has a closing square bracket.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. Just one problem remains. In the 'et_pb_text' square brackets the identifier(id) can be placed at any place in between the square brackets.
https://regex101.com/r/aie0FI/1
You can see in the regex that there are two text elements with id text1 but it is only matching the first one which has id in the start. I tried this one 
https://regex101.com/r/Xbq3Gk/1
But it matches two blocks at once.

Comment: @HasaanCh you can match module_id="text2" not crossing the square brackets like this `(?s)\[et_pb_text [^][]*module_id="text2"[^][]*].*?\[\/et_pb_text]` https://regex101.com/r/8ybnP8/1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229341/discussion-between-hasaanch-and-the-fourth-bird).